# Getting same color output on iOS Simulator versus Quartz drawing in Mac app

Tags: macos, pdf, colors

I have a PDF that seems to have some internal color profile attached. If I render this in iPhone simulator the colors come out as they look in Photoshop which apparently can parse this color profile. If I render the same PDF on Mac I get the same colors (less bright, muddy) as in Preview and Pixelmator.

Is there some way how I can achieve the same (correct) rendering result on Mac as I was getting in iPhone simulator?

On iOS Simulator, I used CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB with a kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst bitmap context. I also set rendering intent kCGRenderingIntentPerceptual, though I don't know if this makes any difference.

on Mac I tried the same settings, as well as all the different kinds of color spaces, but I'm never able to achieve the same result us in Simulator.

I also tried the two ICC based approaches mentioned here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1396/_index.html

I'm getting desperate. What is different between iOS simulator which gets the colors right and Mac? I thought iOS doesn't do color correction, but Mac does? Right now I am drawing the individual pages with PDFKit. Is there a difference in PDFKit on Mac versus iOS related to color correction that makes it work properly on iOS Simulator, but fails on Mac?

I also took a JPG that was rendered from this PDF in iOS Simulator, put it into a new PDF in Preview and there preview and my Mac rendering yielded exactly the same colors as the input.

It looks to me like iOS Simulator has a magical ability to use a color profile embedded in this PDF which Preview or Quartz on Mac does not.

Please help!

kind regards
Oliver Drobnik

Comment: Are the colors you're having trouble with on text? Which version of the simulator are you using?

Comment: No the colors are a shadow that has a golden tint and a large area red that looks washed out.

Comment: I now believe this to be a bug in CGPDF. I filed a Radar and opened an issue with Apple DTS hoping for a workaround: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/bug-quartz-pdf-rendering-with-cmyk-page-level-transparency-blending-color-space/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a confirmed bug in CGPDF on Mac. It manifests itself if you have CMYK as a transparency color space. iOS ignores this correctly, the Mac messes up the colors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how simulator works, but I can assure you that both Preview and iOS have very incorrect handling of certain features of PDF files; especially when it comes to color management, transparency, overprint, advanced compression of images etc...

Two tips:

On Mac, open the PDF file in Adobe Reader (free download from Adobe.com). The color you see in Reader should be very close to the actual truth. If your PDF file contains ICC profiles (for objects in the file or in the output intent, meaning for the whole file) it will be used correctly. On iOS, also look at Adobe Reader - it currently is the best (highest quality) display tool on that platform.

Secondly, if you want to know what the simulator or some other tool can or cannot do, have a look at the test patches from the GWG (http://gwg.org/ghentoutputsuite.phtml). These patches were designed to give very easy to interpret results on whether certain tools or printers can handle specific PDF features.

These two steps should at least tell you what works and where it works. That should make it easier to figure out what you need to correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but they are not touching the main point. The PDF in question does not have a color profile attached. The problem is that iOS Simulator displays it correctly and Preview doesn't. My question is about how to get the same rendering result as in Simulator.

Comment: You've lost me now, your first sentence is "I have a PDF that seems to have some internal color profile attached". So is there or is there not a profile in this PDF? Do you have an example PDF available some where to take a look at?